# Oracle SQL join with outer join operators on 3 tables not returning all desired rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm querying 3 different tables to compile work order data. I'm joining the 3 tables using the outer join operator because I want to return all work orders, regardless of their absence from some of the sub-tables. However, my query is not including all work orders.

For background, here are the 3 tables I'm querying:

```
TABLE_A

|WORK_ORDER|LOCATION|AMOUNT  |
|111111111 |LOCA    |12345.67|
|222222222 |LOCB    |98765.43|

TABLE_B

|WORK_ORDER|SUPP_NBR|SUPP_AMT|
|222222222 |001     |1234.56 |
|222222222 |002     |78.91   |
|222222222 |003     |23456.78|

TABLE_C

|WORK_ORDER|SUPP_NBR|SUPP_TIME|
|222222222 |003     |15       |
```

So a work order will exist in TABLE_A, but may not exist in TABLE_B. If it exists in TABLE_B, it may not necessarily exist in TABLE_C.

My query:

```sql
SELECT A.WORK_ORDER,
       B.SUPP_NBR,
       B.SUPP_AMT,
       C.SUPP_TIME
FROM TABLE_A A,
     TABLE_B B,
     TABLE_C C
WHERE A.WORK_ORDER = B.WORK_ORDER(+)
AND B.WORK_ORDER   = C.WORK_ORDER(+)
AND B.SUPP_NBR     = C.SUPP_NBR(+);
```

Based on my query, I would expect (hope) to return:

```
|WORK_ORDER|SUPP_NBR|SUPP_AMT|SUPP_TIME|
|111111111 |(null)  |(null)  |(null)   |
|222222222 |001     |1234.56 |(null)   |
|222222222 |002     |78.91   |(null)   |
|222222222 |003     |23456.78|15       |
```

However, I am not returning that first row for work order '111111111':

```
|WORK_ORDER|SUPP_NBR|SUPP_AMT|SUPP_TIME|
|222222222 |001     |1234.56 |(null)   |
|222222222 |002     |78.91   |(null)   |
|222222222 |003     |23456.78|15       |
```

I've tried adding a join on the work order for tables A and C, but then that returns only the row in TABLE_C. How do the joins need to be re-structured to include work orders that aren't present in the sub-tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong/unintended with the old school left join syntax you are using.  Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with it, and so can't offer a correction.  But, you would be better off just upgrading to the modern explicit join syntax from the ANSI 92 standard.  The following version of your query behaves as expected:

```
SELECT
    A.WORK_ORDER,
    B.SUPP_NBR,
    B.SUPP_AMT,
    C.SUPP_TIME
FROM TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B
    ON A.WORK_ORDER = B.WORK_ORDER
LEFT JOIN TABLE_C C
    ON B.WORK_ORDER = C.WORK_ORDER AND
       B.SUPP_NBR = C.SUPP_NBR
ORDER BY
    A.WORK_ORDER;
```

### Demo